# Codeigniter deployment problem while hosting to domain server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, cpanel

The project locally works fine $config['base_url'] = "localhost/";

Codeigniter is getting the default controller welcome and login.php,
 but login.php is not getting the resources from assets folder
all the get requests for a resource are not found. When I inspect I get errors
  `xGET example.com/assets/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
      net::ERR_ABORTED 404`
CodeIgniter folder structure in Cpanel **public_html** 
  +application
  +assets
  +system
  index.php
  .htaccess
I've configured the **application/config/config.php**
  `$config['base_url'] = 'www.mysite.com/';
   $config['index_page'] = '';`
I've configured the **application/config/autoload.php**
`$autoload['packages'] = array('url');`
.htaccess
     `RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

the pages are loading resources:-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: use `http` or `https` in base Url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using href="`<?php echo base_url();?>`assets/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> just use href="/assets/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Also, add http:// or https:// to your base URL depending on your SSL status.

Comment: what exactly is your question here ?

Comment: I tried adding http & https to the base_url() and replace the base_url() with /assets but still not getting the resource I thing it has something to do with the mode_rewrite If there is a way to fix this without removing .htaccess from the root direcory and adding an index,php in the app/config/config.php

Comment: Try changing your htaccess file with the following: add - RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] & remove - RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: I've added https and when I changed the capital letters into small letters it worked ->/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/ with /template/loginpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using link_tag from html helper.
First load html helper in controller, or make it autoload in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html');
```

Then try putting this in your header block of view file:

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/TEMPLATE/LoginPage/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>
```